# Get the class structure of an android project

Tags: java, android, project

I've an android project opensource written in Java (Eclipse). There are about 300 classes..I wanna to be able to understand the code quicker and to have a general representation of all the classes, interfaces and to know how they are connected each other.
Is there a way in Eclips or an external utility that could help retrieve the class structure of the project?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168753/application-to-generate-java-class-hierarchy-diagram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried it, but this looks good: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jug/

EDIT: Well this one looks even better: http://www.objectaid.com/home

EDIT 2: See this, too: http://www.nwiresoftware.com/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't done that yet with Java, but you can try some of the options discussed here:

[How to generate UML diagrams (especially sequence diagrams) from Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51786/recommended-eclipse-plugins-to-generate-uml-from-java-code)

to get UML diagrams of your code

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few UML plugins available out there for Eclipse. It's really about how much information you want and which you feel comfortable with. The most popular one I found is **[Object Aid](http://www.objectaid.com/home)** but a **[quick Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=eclipse%20uml%20plugins&sugexp=chrome,mod=0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)** for UML plugins for Eclipse returns a number of options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want detailed UML diagrams then I highly recommend taking a look at [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au). It provides tight integration with Eclipse. The desktop version is quite affordable.