# Identifying the architecture and libraries of an open source app

Tags: java, android, architecture, open-source, libraries

so here I got an [open-source Android app](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss) which I must analyze and identify the structure of, things like its libraries, high-level architecture, configuration management, and testing facilities.

Now I understand where and how to look for the last two, but I still rather confused on how can I identify the libraries and architecture.

So what I'm asking is, how do I identify the architecture of an app and the libraries it uses? where do I look for it? what part of the source code? are there any tips to do this?

If there is any other info that I should provide, please do tell me.

Edit1: this is what I meant by high-level architecture, using Firefox as an example, but it doesn't have to be this technical, something more simple is also okay >>> [image: Mozilla Firefox Architecture]

Comment: What do you mean by "architecture"?

Comment: @TheWanderer added, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: You are using Android-studio. right ?

Comment: @ZeekHuge yep i am using android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 1000s (maybe even millions) of questions on stack-overflow regarding Android development. The android documentation is itself highly exhaustive. And a simple query like "add library android project" can lead someone to [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32381934/4229514).

What I am really trying to say is, a lot is already there. You just need to use it.

As for the original question :

**Libraries**

The dependencies can be found [here](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/blob/master/app/build.gradle#L249). These are the external libraries that are used by this app.

-

**Architecture**

About that, you will mostly have to go through the code. Using [Android-studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/) for that can be really helpful. You can use [tools like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168753/application-to-generate-java-class-hierarchy-diagram), but mostly, you will have to go through the code and understand it.

Furthermore, since its opensource project, there should be good documentation about it.

Comment: I definitely understand on identifying libraries now thanks to you, however, I'm still not clear on the architecture. 

What should I look for in the code? even if I did find every element that can be used to make the architecture diagram, I don't think I will be able to tell how each element connect with each other (like in the Firefox example).

So, is there any simple explanation, example or analogy so I can better understand on how to find the "elements" and how to connect each one? i've tried to browse for such things, but every single one is very different or just plain confusing.

Comment: I guess you figured it out :)

Comment: nah I actually haven't, not your fault though I'm just stupid